# HANA database and SAP hosted in Azure region have high latency

Tags: azure, hana

We are in the middle of migrating from our legacy DC to Azure DC. For one of the systems migrated, we noticed the latency between HANA DB and SAP is more when compared to the old one. The VMs are placed in the same region and also part of proximity placement groups. Is there any other tweaking required to reduce the latency.

Answer (score 0):

I would check net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps are not enabled which cause issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/sap/sap-hana-high-availability

Network configuration parameters recommended in other scenarios for HANA may not be supported on Azure and should be adjusted as recommended by MS, also parameters net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse and net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle should not be enabled if this is the case.